# Showing progress bar while downloading video with libvideo

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I am working on winforms in which I can download videos from youtube using libvideo. I want to show the progress of download too. How can I do this?

```
var youTube = YouTube.Default;
    var video = youTube.GetVideo(link);
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\" + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());
```

Comment: I just checked the documentation and it's there with an example.   **Sample Progress** https://github.com/omansak/libvideo/blob/master/docs/README.md

Comment: I have deleted my answer because the information is available in the documentation. I will add however, that there are some issues with the example, using `Result` inside an `async` method is a bad idea. I saw from the comments you put on my answer that you are new and would like to understand how the example works; in this case I think it's worth gathering your questions and trying to search on them here. If there are not relevant questions already, you can open new ones. The issue with explaining code line for line here is that it breaks away from the clarity of the answer for others.